# Numpy array object or data structure

Tags: python, numpy, object

is python numpy array an object or is it a data structure? How would you conceptual look at it. It confuses me because I can change its internal state by saying a statement as `arr[0 ] = 5`

This makes it a data structure. And I can also call a method by calling `arr.sort()`. This makes it an object like.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you think the distinction between data structure and object is? *Everything* is an object in Python. `arr[0] = 5` is essentially syntactic sugar for `arr.__setitem__(0, 5)`.

Comment: Thanks. I see your point.